# I am getting "Shape type mismatch error" while creating a freeform shape from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run the following code

```
Sub builder()

Dim shpbld As FreeformBuilder
Dim shp As Shape

shpbld = ActiveSheet.Shapes.BuildFreeform(msoEditingAuto, 240.5, 60)
        With shpbld
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 202.25, 60
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 185, 105
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 239.75, 105
            shp = .ConvertToShape.Select
        End With
End Sub
```

However, it is giving type mismatch error for shp.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans. I tried to run after removing the .select. and putting it later. Now it gives "Object variable or With block variable not set" as the error.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Try to include a _Set_ in front of _shp_

Comment: Yes indeed. I was forgetting putting set for shp= ConvertToShape. It works now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning an object to a variable, you need to use the keyword `Set`...

```
Sub builder()

Dim shpbld As FreeformBuilder
Dim shp As Shape

Set shpbld = ActiveSheet.Shapes.BuildFreeform(msoEditingAuto, 240.5, 60)
        With shpbld
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 202.25, 60
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 185, 105
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 239.75, 105
            Set shp = .ConvertToShape
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Domenic. I was thinking it was some kind of silly mistake. I was putting set shpbuild, but didn’t realise i needed to put for set for shp= converToShape too.

Comment: Will the .Textframe.Characters.Text =“text” work in case of such above shapes converted from freeform?

Comment: You're very welcome!  Try `shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "text"`.